# What is the full google voice url for placing calls on iOS?

Tags: ios, google-voice

I know that a phone number formatted googlevoice:4155551234 will launch the google voice app on iPhone/iPad.

However, it looks like this will not initiate a phone call from the number passed in. Skype urls look like

- skype://4155551234?call,

so naturally I tried

- googlevoice:4155551234?call
- googlevoice:4155551234?dial

but to no avail.

Does anyone know which arguments should follow the phone number? Or if the url should have a different format?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one. See [this discussion](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/voice/thread?tid=329fc18dd57dd60b&hl=en).

Comment: Thanks for the link. What use is the googlevoice:/ url if it only launches the app? Seems very limited.