# How do we find the list of VOIP URLschemes registered in the device?

Tags: swift, xcode, voip

I DO NOT want to use the following:

```
if let url = URL( string: "tel://4151231234" )
{
  UIApplication.shared.open( url, options: [:] )
}
```

Instead, I would like to have a list of supported URLschemes in the device that allows making phone calls.  Something that would result in a list a bit like the following:
  "tel://", "whatsapp://", "facetime://", "Hangout://", etc.

The problem using the "tel://" URL scheme is that iOS returns 
iPhone Calls Not Available" on all devices that are not paired
with an iPhone even though they have VOIP apps that supports phone calls.

I do not want to become a VOIP app myself (using CallKit).
But I do not mind using using CallKit IF I don't implement
the entire API to become a phone app.

The Contact App has the behavior that I am looking for:
- When Selecting a contact (in the Apple's contact app),
  Tap on "Call" at the top
- A pop up list of applications supporting phone calls is listed
  including 'Call', "Facetime" and "Hangouts" (in my iPad).
I would like to have the list that allows the Contact app to know which apps (and also which URLschemes) can be used to make phone calls.

I bet it is simple...  I just don't know ;(  Help me please :<

I DO NOT want to use the following:

```
    if let url = URL( string: "tel://4151231234" )
    {   UIApplication.shared.open( url, options: [:] )
    }
```

What would be the code to create a list of apps/URLscheme that support making phone calls?

Comment: Look into [canOpenURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl) and create a list after checking each of the relevant URL Schemes

Comment: canOpenURL() did sound promising; unfortunately, I was unable to make the URLscheme googlevoice:// to work.  There is practically no documentation about it although Google do mention that it exists.  I wish I knew how Apple comes up with their list => My need/question is still OPEN.

Comment: The answer at this link suggests that it cannot be done https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650670/what-is-the-full-google-voice-url-for-placing-calls-on-ios

Comment: That reference to another stackoverflow question is 8 years old.  This is way before Apple changed their OS to iOS 10 allowing VOIP apps to be integrated to the iPhone/iPads.  Additionally, Apple itself DID implement a mechanism to call Hangouts in the iOS Contact apps (I believe in iOS 10.? or 11).  This implementation is still available today in the Contact app just like I describe it above.  So there is a way: Apple does it.  So the question:  what is that way?  and is it available to developers?  Good question and I would like to know...